# convert non-contiguous dot product to neon assembly

Tags: c++, c, converters, simd, neon

Instead of a normal dot product, my application requires a slightly modified version. Here is the original C++ code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < k; m++) {
    for (int n = 0; n < l; n++) {
        for (int t = 0; t < dims2[2]; t++) {
            for (int dm = 0; dm < dims2[1]; dm++) {
                for (int dn = 0; dn < dims2[0]; dn++) {

                    int ai = (n + dn) + (m + dm) * dims1[0] + t * dims1[0] * dims1[1];
                    int bi = dn + dm * dims2[0] + t * dims2[0] * dims2[1];

                    total += A[ai] * B[bi];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to change the order of the loops. How do I convert this to neon assembly?

Comment: Doesn't gcc output neon assembly code: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options

Comment: What's up with that funny order in the first place? Can't you reorder it? It looks like the loop over `dn` really wanted to be the inner loop but somehow a loop over `t` snuck inside.

Comment: @romeric: i don't quite understand (even from the link), can u please elaborate?

Comment: @harold: changed the loop structure. feel free to change it to any other order if it helps in converting to neon

Comment: It may even autovectorize now, but you can use `vmla_s32` to multiply 4 ints from a with 4 ints from b and add them to a partial total. Make sure to do any extra iterations that weren't a multiple of 4 too. You can do the horizontal sum of the partial sums all the way in the end of the function.

Comment: Sometimes compilers a not as smart as one would think. Try to precalculate `ai` and `bi` in outer loop to have just `A[ai+dn]*B[bi+dn]` in the innermost loop